# Can a classical Toffoli gate be built from irreversible gates?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, computer-architecture

The Toffoli gate is a reversible gate with three inputs (A, B, C) and three outputs (S1, S2, S3) generated as

- S1 = A
- S2 = B
- S3 = AB ^ C

It can be implemented in a classic way using the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP6aLS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, the AND gate and the XOR gate are not reversible. Hence, is this implementation of the Toffoli gate actually reversible?. More generic in a mathematical way, given a homomorphism, can it be implemented using irreversible gates?.

Comment: This is not the same as [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate).

Comment: Sorry @CL. I made a mistake writting the expression. Now it should be correct :)

Comment: What happens when you put two Toffoli gates in series?

Comment: **The common AND gate is not reversible, however. The inputs 00, 01 and 10 are all mapped to the output 0.**  By this definition from the wikipedia site, No.